# Retrieve the formulas from the Salesforce Formula fields

Tags: salesforce, sfdc, sfdc-metadata-api, cdata-drivers

I am looking for a way to get the formulas from Salesforce Formula fields. We are using the CDATA Drivers to connect to Salesforce. But I am not seeing any option to retrieve the Salesforce formulas.

Answer (score 4):

No idea what "cdata drivers" are so hopefully some of these will point you in right direction.

In Apex you can use "[describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm)" calls. If all other options fail - you could build a custom service that returns this data to you.

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Account.Address__c.getDescribe();
System.debug(dfr.getCalculatedFormula());
// BillingStreet & BR() & BillingCity & BR() &  BillingPostalCode & BR() &  BillingCountry & BR() &  Street2__c & BR() & Street3__c
```

You've tagged [metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm) so if you really use that - similar info should be available in it.

```
<CustomField>
    <fullName>Address__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <formula>BillingStreet &amp; BR() &amp; BillingCity &amp; BR() &amp;  BillingPostalCode &amp; BR() &amp;  BillingCountry &amp; BR() &amp;  Street2__c &amp; BR() &amp; Street3__c</formula>
    <formulaTreatBlanksAs>BlankAsZero</formulaTreatBlanksAs>
    <label>Address</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</CustomField>
```

In [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm) it's similar, a call to `/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/describe` will return (among others)

```
{
    "aggregatable" : true,
    "aiPredictionField" : false,
    "autoNumber" : false,
    "byteLength" : 3900,
    "calculated" : true,
    "calculatedFormula" : "BillingStreet & BR() & BillingCity & BR() &  BillingPostalCode & BR() &  BillingCountry & BR() &  Street2__c & BR() & Street3__c",
    "cascadeDelete" : false,
    (...)
    "formulaTreatNullNumberAsZero" : true,
    "groupable" : false,
    "highScaleNumber" : false,
    "htmlFormatted" : true,
    "idLookup" : false,
    "inlineHelpText" : null,
    "label" : "Address",
    "length" : 1300,
    "mask" : null,
    "maskType" : null,
    "name" : "Address__c",
    (...)
    "type" : "string",
    "unique" : false,
    "updateable" : false,
    "writeRequiresMasterRead" : false
  }
```

And finally there's [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm) where you can query the metadata like you'd query normal database tables. But the core of what you need will be hidden in a JSON field you'd have to parse. If your tool is some ETL - check if it can query `FieldDefinition` table.

`/services/data/v48.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Metadata+FROM+FieldDefinition+WHERE+EntityDefinitionId+=+'Account'+AND+QualifiedApiName+=+'Address__c'`

Comment: Thanks eyescream. Metadata field is exactly what I was looking for. But it appears that the CData Drivers for Salesforce doesn't expose that, or at least I haven't found a way to get the Metadata field using the CData Drivers for Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

CData Salesforce driver exposes a view called: 'Formulas' which you can query to get the available formula definition.
Documentation: https://cdn.cdata.com/help/RFJ/jdbc/pg_table-formulas.htm